# Scala annotations are not found

Tags: scala, macros, annotations, scala-macros

I have a case class with annotated fields, like this:

```
case class Foo(@alias("foo") bar: Int)
```

I have a macro that processes the declaration of this class:

```
val (className, access, fields, bases, body) = classDecl match {
  case q"case class $n $m(..$ps) extends ..$bs { ..$ss }" => (n, m, ps, bs, ss)
  case _ => abort
}
```

Later, I search for the aliased fields, as follows:

```
val aliases = fields.asInstanceOf[List[ValDef]].flatMap {
  field => field.symbol.annotations.collect {
  //deprecated version:
  //case annotation if annotation.tpe <:< cv.weakTypeOf[alias] =>
    case annotation if annotation.tree.tpe <:< c.weakTypeOf[alias] =>
    //deprecated version:
    //annotation.scalaArgs.head match {
      annotation.tree.children.tail.head match {
        case Literal(Constant(param: String)) => (param, field.name)
      }
  }
}
```

However, the list of aliases ends up being empty. I have determined that field.symbol.annotations.size is, in fact, 0, despite the annotation clearly sitting on the field.

Any idea of what's wrong?

**EDIT**

Answering the first two comments:

(1) I tried mods.annotations, but that didn't work. That actually returns List[Tree] instead of List[Annotation], returned by symbol.annotations. Perhaps I didn't modify the code correctly, but the immediate effect was an exception during macro expansion. I'll try to play with it some more.

(2) The class declaration is grabbed while processing an annotation macro slapped on the case class.

The complete code follows. The usage is illustrated in the test code further below.

```
package com.xxx.util.macros

import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait Mapped {
  def $(key: String) = _vals.get(key)

  protected def +=(key: String, value: Any) =
    _vals += ((key, value))

  private var _vals = new HashMap[String, Any]
}

class alias(val key: String) extends StaticAnnotation

class aliased extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro aliasedMacro.impl
}

object aliasedMacro {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    val (classDecl, compDecl) = annottees.map(_.tree) match {
      case (clazz: ClassDef) :: Nil => (clazz, None)
      case (clazz: ClassDef) :: (comp: ModuleDef) :: Nil => (clazz, Some(comp))
      case _ => abort(c, "@aliased must annotate a class")
    }

    val (className, access, fields, bases, body) = classDecl match {
      case q"case class $n $m(..$ps) extends ..$bs { ..$ss }" => (n, m, ps, bs, ss)
      case _ => abort(c, "@aliased is only supported on case class")
    }

    val mappings = fields.asInstanceOf[List[ValDef]].flatMap {
      field => field.symbol.annotations.collect {
        case annotation if annotation.tree.tpe <:< c.weakTypeOf[alias] =>
          annotation.tree.children.tail.head match {
            case Literal(Constant(param: String)) =>
              q"""this += ($param, ${field.name})"""
          }
      }
    }

    val classCode = q"""
      case class $className $access(..$fields) extends ..$bases {
        ..$body; ..$mappings
      }"""

    c.Expr(compDecl match {
      case Some(compCode) => q"""$compCode; $classCode"""
      case None => q"""$classCode"""
    })
  }

  protected def abort(c: whitebox.Context, message: String) =
    c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, message)
}
```

The test code:

```
package test.xxx.util.macros

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import com.xxx.util.macros._

@aliased
case class Foo(@alias("foo") foo: Int,
               @alias("BAR") bar: String,
                             baz: String) extends Mapped

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MappedTest extends FunSuite {
  val foo = 13
  val bar = "test"
  val obj = Foo(foo, bar, "extra")

  test("field aliased with its own name") {
    assertResult(Some(foo))(obj $ "foo")
  }

  test("field aliased with another string") {
    assertResult(Some(bar))(obj $ "BAR")
    assertResult(None)(obj $ "bar")
  }

  test("unaliased field") {
    assertResult(None)(obj $ "baz")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `field.mods.annotations`? I don't think the field will even have a symbol that you can read the annotation off of, but looking at its modifiers should work.

Comment: How does this macro get hold of the declaration of the class?

Comment: Thanks! Please see the edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions! In the end, using field.mods.annotations did help. This is how:

```
val mappings = fields.asInstanceOf[List[ValDef]].flatMap {
  field => field.mods.annotations.collect {
    case Apply(Select(New(Ident(TypeName("alias"))), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR),
               List(Literal(Constant(param: String)))) =>
      q"""this += ($param, ${field.name})"""
  }
}
```